# ADD and Multiply array data in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to ADD and Multiply array data in codeigniter. I am using the following models  **best_outlet_chart()**

```
function best_outlet_chart(){

        $this->db->select(array(
            'tbl_outlet_registration.outlet_name',
            'tbl_sub_products.sub_product_price',
            'tbl_order_products.quantity',
        ));

        $this->db->from('tbl_outlet_registration');
        $this->db->join('tbl_order_product_details', 'tbl_order_product_details.outlet_id=tbl_outlet_registration.outlet_id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_order_products', 'tbl_order_products.order_id=tbl_order_product_details.order_id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_sub_products', 'tbl_sub_products.sub_product_id=tbl_order_products.product_id','LEFT');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

the above code return an array some thing like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [outlet_name] => Outlet A
            [sub_product_price] => 1000.00
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [outlet_name] => Outlet A
            [sub_product_price] => 50.00
            [quantity] => 50
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [outlet_name] => Outlet B
            [sub_product_price] => 10.00
            [quantity] => 70
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [outlet_name] => Outlet B
            [sub_product_price] => 10.00
            [quantity] => 1
        )
)
```

I want to multiply [sub_product_price] with the [quantity] (sub_product_price*quantity)  in **Outlet A** and other outlets respectively. Not all outlets together but separately.Can some one please help me with this

Thanks!!
Ann

I used the following code and it give me the total of all outlets not separately .

```
'SUM(tbl_sub_products.sub_product_price * tbl_order_products.quantity) as amount'
```

Comment: Use GROUP BY outlet_name. This will group the different outlets

Comment: Yes but it will not  multiply [sub_product_price] with the [quantity] (sub_product_price*quantity)

Comment: It will. So you can use 'SUM(tbl_sub_products.sub_product_price * tbl_order_products.quantity) as amount' and then at last use GROUP BY outlet_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm not having the database table structure, I prepare a separate table with the columns you mention.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_outlet` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `outlet_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sub_product_price` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

You can use something like this to fetch your result

```
SELECT outlet_name, SUM( (
`sub_product_price` * `quantity`
) ) AS `total_amount`
FROM `tbl_outlet`
GROUP BY `outlet_name`
```